# How to remove individual calendars from Gnome Calendar in Bionic Beaver

Tags: gnome, 18.04, calendar, online-accounts

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 from 16.04. I noticed that there are several (around 12) calendars associated with my Google Calendar account. I would like to disable most **but not all** of them.
**How can I do that?**

Part of the reason why I want to do that is that

1. I'm getting prompts for passwords every time I open Calendar, which is annoying.
2. There are duplicate entries (not sure why).
3. I don't need information on many of these calendars on a daily basis, I can just use Google Calendar.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Very irritating and I don't want Google anywhere near my computer

Answer (score 0):

If you got to "Calendar Settings" you can select/click on the calendar you want to hide.
[image: Calendar Settings]

Then there will be an option to display it or not display it.
[image: Display Settings]

This will **not** fix your problem with Gnome Calendar asking for your credentials. If you want to stop that from happening, you will need to remove the online account (System Settings > Online Accounts). If this is a Google account you could generate an "application password" for Ubuntu, that would bypass two factor authentication and is designed for permanent access, which is what you for Ubuntu whereas passwords + 2FA are what you want for ephemeral web logins.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting my google account did not work. I logged out & in after deleting the online account and I still have the prompts for the calendar passwords.

Deleting (including configuration files) gnome-calendar did not work either. The calendars are still there.

I think it has something to do with the evolution backend.

~/.config/evolution/sources had some files with my google account. I deleted those, logged in/out and the calendars are gone.